# Is there a way to check node and npm versions before a npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I want to only allow certain version of node and npm before the user can run his `npm install` on my module.

In [the NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines), there is an `engine` attribute, dedicated to this task:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.0.0",
    "npm": ">=3.0.0"
  }
```

These parameters will only allow node and npm versions up to 4 and 3.

However, the documentation says that the `engine-strict` attribute should be enabled in order to check the versions. On `engine-strict`, [it is said that](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#enginestrict):

> This feature was deprecated with npm 3.0.0

So, is there a way, with npm3, to define minimal Node and NPM versions for a module?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60124530/320399 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/61403815/320399

Answer (score 3):

Yarn checks the engine out of the box at the time of installation. But with npm, you may have to write a custom validator at this moment for checking node versions before firing a script.

```
export function verifyNodeVersion(version) {
  const nodeVersion = process.versions.node;
  if (!nodeVersion.startsWith(`${version}.`)) {
    throw new Error(
      `Incorrect version of Node found: ${nodeVersion}, Expected: v${version}.x`
    );
  }
  console.log('Current Node version:', nodeVersion);
  return true;
}
```

And call the function in the entry points.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there a way, with npm3, to define minimal Node and NPM versions for a module?

`engines` does that. It's just that it does it by A) Outputting an advisory message warning the user if their system isn't up-to-scratch, and B) Failing **if** the user has set the [`engine-strict` config flag](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#engine-strict).

All the documentation is saying is that `engineStrict` is no longer supported to push the user around. :-) If they want to ignore the advisory messages and not use the `engine-strict` config flag, then *caveat user*.