# How to throw "Lower Node Version Found in Package" error when installing NPM package having node version higher than current system node version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, npm

I want to throw an error when installing an NPM package if the node version supported by that module is lower/higher than the system/server node version.

My use case is, I do not want to install any npm module having node version support for 8 and below.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Even if the module also supports the version you are running? You are in for a bad time - most libraries try to support older versions on purpose. Is, say, lodash any less important even though it supports node 4+? And this would affect any dependencies of your dependencies. What are you hoping to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @Joe Basically In case a module does not older version like we get warnings in some modules that we are deprecating for node version 4 and below etc. I want to find a way on how do we find out the node version of a package when installing it (npm install xyz) and throw or print warning msg.

Answer (score 0):

**This feature apparently doesn't work, despite the documentation to the contrary.  I can't get it to trigger anyway.**

If you want strict checking of supported node versions, use the `engine-strict` flag to npm.

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#engine-strict

```
npm config set engine-strict true
npm i
```

You should also be able to do

```
npm i --engine-strict
```

will force checking of the `engines` sections in the installed modules and refuse to install if any of the modules don't meet the current system's installed versions of node (and npm, if specified.)

Do not confuse this with the deprecated `engineStrict` package.json key; that's different.

Comment: I think this has been broken in NPM for 5 years.