# JS: nvmrc vs package.json engines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I am trying to lock node and npm version in my javascript project to ensure other developers have those specific versions when building bundles to commit.  I just added this to my package.json:

```
  "engineStrict" : true,
  "engines": {
    "node" : "10.10.0",
    "npm" : "6.5.0"
  },
```

Will this enforce those versions definitively?  I am unfamiliar with locking down versions since I am used to be the sole developer on frontend projects or inheriting projects that have had this set up.
Alternatively, is there a benefit of also adding an `.nvmrc` file that specifies the same version or is that redundant if I'm using engines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I specify the required Node.js version in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349684/how-can-i-specify-the-required-node-js-version-in-package-json)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60124530/320399

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Enforcing Node.js version

`engineStrict` is deprecated since npm v3, but you can set `engine-strict=true` in your .npmrc file. If you have `engines` set in package.json, an error will be thrown when someone installs on an unsupported Node.js version.

### .nvmrc for developer convenience

To make it easier for other developers to use a supported Node.js version, you can add a .nvmrc file. Now other developers can run `nvm use` to automatically use a supported version.

Comment: Thanks @elias .  I assume that if I go the .nvmrc route rather than using engines, I can't specify npm versions though, right?

Comment: You don't need to choose :). They complement each other: package.json + .npmrc enforces the version, .nvmrc makes it easier for others to use the right version.

Comment: just so I am clear....if I'm writing a module I expect others to install, I would set the "engines" field in my package.json.  If I'm an app that uses the dep AND the dep set their engines field, then I ONLY need to have set the engines-strict config in .npmrc.  IE setting the engines field in a package.json that's not used as a dep someplace else, doesn't appear to have any value.   If I set "engines" to Node 12 in my app, I can run all my package scripts in node 8.....and nothing complains